# upload file with nodejs, multer, react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

I am trying to upload files from the frontend (in react) and save to the filesystem in the server. When I make the request to the server, the request is successful, but the files are not saved to my filesystem. When I console.log the req.file, I get an "undefined" (in the server side).

server.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const childProcess = require('child_process');
//const { request } = require('express');
const multer = require("multer");

app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '500000mb'}));


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, "upload/");
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        console.log(req);
        cb(null, "test.png");
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage});

app.post("/model", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send("files received");
})


app.use(express.static('build'));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

addBtn.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class AddBtn extends Component{
   
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="form">
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/model">
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddBtn;
```

when I console.log(req.files) I get:

```
{ file:
   { fieldName: 'file',
     originalFilename: 'requerimento.png',
     path: '/tmp/37648-1b0v335.qt09.png',
     headers:
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="requerimento.png"',
        'content-type': 'image/png' },
     ws:
      WriteStream {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        path: '/tmp/37648-1b0v335.qt09.png',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        autoClose: true,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 30082,
        closed: true },
     size: 30082,
     name: 'requerimento.png',
     type: 'image/png' } }
```

when I console.log inside filename: function, it doesn't print anything on the screen

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3ePnBWFH9o and it worked, but when I tried to implement it in my code (that uses react) it failed and I don't know why. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Lucas, I can't spot anything wrong at first sight. Question, why is axios imported if not used in the component? How big is the file you're uploading?

Comment: Read the docs careeeeeefully.

Comment: sorry maxim, I was trying to use axios at first. But then I just gave up and made the request directly in the html. The file has 30kb (.png image).

Comment: @LucasMiyazaki can you change `cb(null, "test.png");` to `cb(null, file.originalname);` and see what happens? Also add a `console.log(file)` above that line.

Comment: @MaximOrlov I wrote console.log(file) before cb(null, file.originalname) and it printed "undefined" on the server console. It is still not working when I changed it to file.originalname.

Comment: @LucasMiyazaki Very weird. What do you get when you console.log `req.headers`? It might be something in the frontend.

Comment: @MaximOrlov I also get undefined

Comment: @LucasMiyazaki headers can't be undefined, every request has at least some headers. Is it printing undefined or not printing anything at all? The second would suggest the function isn't called. Add a logging middleware right after `express()`. Something like this: `app.use((req, res) => console.log(req.headers);next(););

Comment: ops my mistake, I was console.loging somewhere else. When I console.log(file) before res.send("files received"); i get undefined. But when I console.log(files) I get a json something like {file: ...}. But I can't console.log before cb(null, file.originalname), it doesn't print anything on the screen.

Comment: header:{ host: 'localhost:5000',
  'user-agent':
   'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
  accept:
   'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-type':
   'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------166330925339005258713972362584',
  'content-length': '1158777',
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  referer: 'http://localhost:5000/',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1' }

Comment: @LucasMiyazaki Something logging as undefined or not logging at all are two *very* different things. When it's logging/printing `undefined` it means a variable doesn't exist. When it's not logging at all it means code execution never reaches the console.log line. Make sure to distinguish between the two to not confuse others. `req.files` assumes you're using multer.array() or multer.fields() somewhere else in your code. Can you edit your question to include your latest version of server.js with all the code inside it?

Comment: @MaximOrlov I didn't used multer.array() in my code. It is printing undefined when I console.log(req.file) and it is not printing anything at all when I console.log inside the middleware function. The only thing I altered in my code was the console.log.